# How to separate street suffixes from street names when they aren't separated by a space?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right now I have a list of 230,000 street addresses in Excel where the street name and address are in a single column without any delimiter. Some addresses appear with no suffix, most have an abbreviated suffix (Ex. St), and some have the full spelled out suffix (Ex. STREET.

For Example 123 Main Street appears as 123 MAINST

Additionally some suffixes have directions after them EX. STS should become Street South

Right now my best attempt is to use a combination of if statements, index(match), and the Right() function. This works to separate and convert "ST" to "Street" but requires a new function for each abbreviation.

[image]

I have put together a list of the most common suffixes that make up 99%+ of the list. While capturing 100% of addresses would be preferable 90%+ would be acceptable.

I have virtually no VBA experience, so any help using strictly excel formulas would be preferred, but help of any kind would be greatly appreciated.

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please let me know if I broke any rules/conventions.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)          and              [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: if it's vital information i'd look for an excel addin that makes a call to a web servers that does address validation and then provides a properly formateted address.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a reference table containing original messy Street Types alongside their clean version

| row | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | **ORIGINAL** | **CLEAN** |
| 8 | AV | AVENUE |
| 9 | AVE | AVENUE |
| 10 | AV. | AVENUE |
| 11 | ST | STREET |
| 12 | ST. | STREET |
| 13 | CR | CRESCENT |
| 14 | CRES | CRESCENT |
| 15 | CT | COURT |
| 16 | CRT | COURT |
| 17 |  |  |

Then starting at cell E2 down, I added the formula: =INDEX($H$7:$H$12,MATCH(RIGHT($B2,D2),$G$7:$G$12,0))

Then I added at cell D2 down the following formula to handle in a simple way potential abbreviated Street Type lengths of matching 3 character lengths, then 2 character lengths.

=IF(ISBLANK($B2),"",IFNA(MATCH(RIGHT($B2,3),$G$7:$G$12,0),(MATCH(RIGHT(B2,2),$G$7:$G$12,0))))

To consider, some original Street Names lacking Street Type suffix may inadvertently be a match.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have your data in A3, I would highly recommend modifying this formula for all the filters you have for street.

=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("st", LOWER(A3))), "Street", "")

Decomposition of formula:
Find("your search character", LOWER(CELL)) finds the character number from the left that "your search character" is in. The LOWER(CELL) makes it so that you can filter for both St and st. However "your search character" has to be lower case.
ISNUMBER() returns True if your search character was found in the cell address.

I would approach this problem with multiple search columns, then wrapping a unique column for all the street names. With 233000 data points whatever formula you write will not work for all street types, but you can minimize the ones you need to search for manually, by searching for multiple key words (like: street, st, avenue, ave, cres,...)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).